# djangoappengine User Creation and Data Persistence is Broken

Tags: python, django, djangoappengine

I recently updated to appengine SDK 1.6 and I'm having trouble with persisting data on my dev environment. I have everything setup according to the official [installation guide](http://www.allbuttonspressed.com/projects/djangoappengine).

Even though I had a super user account setup for my app previously, it no longer works. I created the account again with

```
manage.py createsuperuser
```

and it seems to do what it's supposed to but the admin login doesn't work. Also, every time I run

```
manage.py syncdb
```

The script keeps informing me that I just install the auth system and don't have any users yet. Then it prompts me to create a super user.

Because nothing is persisting, I can't login to the admin page and any data I attempt to save using the built in shell doesn't keep either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't end up changing anything but after trying it again on my Win 7 machine the next day, the issue wasn't there so it unfortunately isn't reproducible right now. Maybe logging out and logging back in changed some type of state after the install, that's my best guess. Sorry that I don't have any further information.

Answer (score 0):

is it possible that you fire up a new issue at the issue tracker https://github.com/django-nonrel/djangoappengine/issues or at the mailing list http://groups.google.com/group/django-non-relational ? I think there might be a bug somewhere.

Comment: I could also do that, yes. But this really isn't an answer. You should comment on the question instead.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what you upgraded from, it's possible that you previously had no ['default partition'](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/devserver.html#default_partition) value - earlier versions didn't set one by default, but recent ones use 'dev:'. Try giving a `--default_partition` argument to `manage.py`.

Comment: The manage.py that's provided with djangoappengine doesn't have a default_partition subcommand.

Comment: Sorry, that's true. Are you using the latest checkout of djangoappengine? It looks like Waledmar made a commit a month ago that addresses this very issue: https://bitbucket.org/wkornewald/djangoappengine/changeset/60c2b3339a9f

Comment: I got the latest last night and it does include that commit.

Comment: An issue needs to be reported since the problem isn't trivial. The machine I was trying last night was a Win 7 64-bit machine and I tried the same code on my Debian machine and the data persists.